# Etymology for "loganamnosis"

Tags: etymology

It's a condition in which one suffers the inability to remember to the word he or she wants to use and then becomes obsessed with trying to remember it.

What is this interesting word's root? Could someone tell me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like a purpose-created, pseudo-medical neologism to me, like *[pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis](https://www.wordnik.com/words/pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis)*— except there aren't any results at all in CHAE or Google Ngrams. Elsewhere on the web I can only find it in lists of too-clever words, and not in any online dictionaries.

The etymology, I think, is reasonably clear:

- *log-* This is from the *[λόγος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dlo%2Fgos)* (*logos*), Greek for *word* or *speech*.
- *-anamn-* This comes, via Latin, from the Greek *ἀνάμνησις* (*anamnesis*), for  *remembering* or *recollection*.
- *[-osis](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/-osis)* This is a suffix denoting a state or condition, especially a disorder or abnormality, and also [traceable to Greek](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=-osis) via Latin.

Hence *loganamnosis*, a psychotic obsession about remembering words. Considering its obscurity, I wouldn't use it myself, especially considering there is a much better-attested word available:

> *[onomatomania](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/onomatomania)* n. An abnormal concentration on certain words and their supposed significance or on the effort to recall a particular word. [Stedman's]

Answer (score 2):

***Loganamnosis*** dates from at least 1958, as listed in *[Reversicon: A Medical Word Finder](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt/search?q1=loganamnosis;id=mdp.39015018605710;view=1up;seq=7;start=1;sz=10;page=search;orient=0)* by Jacob Edward Schmidt:

[image: Preoccupation, morbid, with attempt to recall forgotten name]

> Preoccupation, morbid, with attempt to recall forgotten name . . . . **NOMANAMNOSIS**
>
> Preoccupation, morbid, with attempt to recall forgotten word . . . . **LOGANAMNOSIS**

Comment: That someone created a word, implying a psychiatric illness, for when someone asks more than once what a person's name is, _that_ sounds like its own morbid preoccupation with other people's minimal personality quirks.

Comment: Wouldn't anamnesis mean NOT forgetting? Since amnesia is from a+mnes?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: No, it's not a+ but ana+, from *ana* + *mimneskein*, *back* + *to remember*. [EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=anamnesis) says: "recollection, remembrance," 1650s, from Greek *anamnesis* "a calling to mind, remembrance," noun of action from stem of *anamimneskein* "to remember, to remind (someone) of (something), make mention of," from *ana* "back" (see ana-) + mimneskesthai "to recall, cause to remember" (see amnesia).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Hugo. Forgot my Greek (what little I ever knew).