# The word for "a word that you forgot"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for "a word that you forgot"? In the situation before you found out or remembered the meaning of the word, how could this word be described? Not "the unknown" or "the forgotten".

"Lethologica" is the condition of being unable to remember, but not the word itself.

Comment: If you wanted to *use* the word you couldn't remember, take your pick from ***thingummyjig, whatsit, doodah, whatchamacallit,*** etc. But if you actually want to *reference* it you'd probably just have to say something like *some word I can't recall right now*.

Comment: I'm sure there's a word for it, but I can't remember what it is…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Darn!  It was right on the tip of my tongue until I read your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with **dingus**, for which the *American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2011) offers a very suitable definition:

> **dingus** *n. Informal* **1.** Something whose name is unknown or forgotten. ... {Dutch *dinges*, whatchamacallit < German *Dings* < Middle High German *dinges*, genitive of *dinc*, thing < Old High German *ding*, *thing*, assembly, case, thing.}

Sam Spade makes good, careless use of the term—to indicate his equivocal interest in the object of everyone else's desire—in John Huston's 1941 version of [*The Maltese Falcon*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ju4N13jD8H8C&pg=PA74&dq=%22the+dingus%22+Spade&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT2-2utJLWAhVIrFQKHbbtBXwQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20dingus%22&f=false):

> SPADE: What's your idea of a fair bargain?
>
> GUTMAN: I will give you twenty-five thousand dollars when you deliver the Falcon to me and another twenty-five thousand later on, or, I will give you one quarter of what I realize on the Falcon. That would amount to a vastly greater sum.
>
> SPADE: How much greater?
>
> GUTMAN: Who knows? Shall we say a hundred thousand? Will you believe me if I name a sum that seems the probable minimum?
>
> SPADE: Why not?
>
> GUTMAN (*placing his hand on Spade's knee again*): What would you say to a quarter of a million?
>
> SPADE: Then you think the **dingus** is worth a million, huh?
>
> GUTMAN: In your own words, "Why not?"

Spade calls the Falcon "the dingus" again somewhat later in the movie, just in case you (or Casper Gutman, to whom he is speaking) might think he was beginning to feel more attentive to and interested in the statuette as a possible possession.

Answer (score 0):

[From wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loganamnosis)

> **loganamnosis** :(formal, rare) an obsession with recalling a specific word that has been forgotten

... and this in turn usually causes *nagging feeling*

and please check  [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223003/etymology-for-loganamnosis)

Comment: Leaving my clothes on the floor is usually produces a "nagging feeling" for me.

Comment: ... or one may have "nagging feeling" of "whatsit" as @FumbleFingers suggested

Answer (score -1):

**Disremembered.**

From [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disremember):

> **disremember**
>   transitive verb  :  forget

A forgotten word would be a disremembered word.